# How to ensure IIS website is completely stopped in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis

I've got a Powershell script that stops an IIS website and corresponding app pool and then deletes the app logs (log4net logs). Here is the script snippet:

```
stop-website -name "MyWebsite"
stop-webapppool -name "MyWebsite"
del c:\inetpub\MyWebsite\logs\*.*
```

The problem is stop-website and stop-webapppool seem to return before the website is completely shutdown which results in the delete failing saying the file is being used by another process:

> del : Cannot remove item C:\inetpub\MyWebsite\logs\App.log: The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\MyWebsite\logs\App.log' because it is being used by another process.

If I add a 10 second sleep between the stop commands and the del command then the logs are deleted successfully. This is very hackish though and not reliable. Is there a way to force the stop-website/stop-webapppool commands to not return until the website/apppool is completely stopped?

Thanks.

---

Implemented solution from the below link. I will wait ~60 seconds and then kill the IIS process if it hasn't stopped.

https://greenfinch.ie/blog/powershellscript.html

```
        "Stopping IIS site [$name]" >> $logFile
        stop-website -name $name

        "Stopping app pool [$name]" >> $logFile
        stop-webapppool -name $name

        $sleepTime = 5
        $processId = $TRUE
        while ($processId)
        {
            $processId = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_process -filter "name='w3wp.exe'" |
                            ?{ ($_.CommandLine).Split("`"")[1] -eq $name } |
                            %{ $_.ProcessId }

            if ($sleepTime -gt 60)
            {
                "Waited [$sleepTime] sec for process [$processId] to stop and it is still running. Killing it." >> $logFile
                Stop-Process $processId
                break
            }

            if ($processId)
            {
                "App pool [$name] is running with process ID: [$processId]. Sleeping for [$sleepTime] sec and then checking again." >> $logFile
                Start-Sleep -s $sleepTime
                $sleepTime = $sleepTime + 10
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use these two commands to check the status of the website/app, say after 10 seconds, then use an If statement to delete logs only when the status returned is `stopped`

```
Get-WebsiteState -name "MyWebsite"
Get-WebAppPoolState -name "MyWebsite"
```

This loop should help you too

```
$currentRetry = 0;
$success = $false;
do{
    $status = Get-WebAppPoolState -name "MyWebsite"
    if ($status -eq "Stopped"){
         <....your code here....>
            $success = $true;
        }
        Start-Sleep -s 10
        $currentRetry = $currentRetry + 1;
    }
while (!$success -and $currentRetry -le 4)
```

**Updated Apr 24, 2019**

Based on comment and current [cmdlet document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/get-webapppoolstate?view=win10-ps), it appears the return type is indeed an object. Thus presumably can be handled as commented or the line snippet below. Author no longer have access to Windows Server environment therefore did not directly modify original answer nor able to test the update

```
if ($status.Value -eq "Stopped")
```

Comment: One tweak I did to get the app pool state as a string:

$status = (Get-WebAppPoolState -name "MyWebsite").Value

Comment: This does not work. $status is an object. You will have to get the Value of that object as is stated on the previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

After you run 'Stop-WebAppPool' the state of the WebAppPool will be "Stopping" and it may take a few seconds before the state of the WebAppPool is actually "Stopped".
Here is a little function to help with the WebAppPoolState

```
function Stop-AppPool ($webAppPoolName,[int]$secs) {
$retvalue = $false
$wsec = (get-date).AddSeconds($secs)
Stop-WebAppPool -Name $webAppPoolName
Write-Output "$(Get-Date) waiting up to $secs seconds for the WebAppPool '$webAppPoolName' to stop"
$poolNotStopped = $true
while (((get-date) -lt $wsec) -and $poolNotStopped) {
    $pstate =  Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $webAppPoolName
    if ($pstate.Value -eq "Stopped") {
        Write-Output "$(Get-Date): WebAppPool '$webAppPoolName' is stopped"
        $poolNotStopped = $false
        $retvalue = $true
    }
}
return $retvalue
}
```

you can run this function using e.g.

```
Stop-AppPool "MyWebsite" 30
```

and check the return-value to see if the WebAppPool has stopped within the given seconds

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to stop the app pool and get it into Stopped state is to use `appcmd.exe`. It will return when the app pool is really stopped or you'll get an error

Just do this on PowerShell:

```
& $env:windir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe stop apppool /apppool.name:"YourAppPoolName"
```

When your AppPool is correctly stooped you'll get this message:

> "YourAppPoolName" successfully stopped

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it with Get-IISServerManager.

```
$manager = Get-IISServerManager      
$site = $manager.Sites["mySiteName"]

if($site.State -ne "Stopped") {
  $site.Stop()
}

while ($site.State -ne "Stopped") {
  "waiting 1 second for site to stop..."
  Start-Sleep -s 1
}

"site stopped"
```

Answer (score 1):

I fix the @user4531 code It would be failed if the app pool is stopped before :

```powershell
function Stop-AppPool ($webAppPoolName,[int]$secs) {
    $retvalue = $false
    $wsec = (get-date).AddSeconds($secs)

    $pstate =  Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $webAppPoolName

    if($pstate.Value -eq "Stopped") {
         Write-Output "WebAppPool '$webAppPoolName' is stopped already"
         return $true
    }

    Stop-WebAppPool -Name $webAppPoolName
    Write-Output "$(Get-Date) waiting up to $secs seconds for the WebAppPool '$webAppPoolName' to stop"
    $poolNotStopped = $true
    while (((get-date) -lt $wsec) -and $poolNotStopped) {
        $pstate =  Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $webAppPoolName
        if ($pstate.Value -eq "Stopped") {
            Write-Output "WebAppPool '$webAppPoolName' is stopped"
            $poolNotStopped = $false
            $retvalue = $true
        }
    }
    return $retvalue
}
```

It can use like this :

```powershell
Stop-AppPool "SSO" 30
```

Comment: Just a note to anyone experiencing the problem the OP described. I implemented this solution, but unfortunately (and surprisingly) it didn't resolve the issue with files being locked. I think there must be a disconnect between the application pool stopping and the file system actually releasing the files. In the end I had to add a simple wait, per the OP's original solution.